# Fedex API - Request rate for different types of packages

Tags: c#, .net, fedex

I want to get quotes from Fedex rate API for shipments with several packages of different types. I'm importing the WSDL file and create a web reference in a .NET/C# project. The service works OK, I get a quote whenever I send a request to the API.

However, I can't find the way to add a new type of package to the "Request" object.

**Example of shipment: 2 Medium Boxes and 1 Small Box.**

The "PackagingType" property is at the top level, so I cannot create a collection of different groups:

```
request.RequestedShipment.PackagingType = PackagingType.YOUR_PACKAGING;
```

There is a collection that you can add to the shipment details, but this doesn't seem to work There's no way to add items to this collection and assign a different type of package

```
request.RequestedShipment.RequestedPackageLineItems[0].PackagingType //does not exist
```

How can I create groups of different types of packages in the same shipment?

Comment: Are you sure it is even possible? Could be that 1 shipment = 1 box/package?

Comment: Well, not really, but the online rate tool gives that option: https://www.fedex.com/ratefinder/home. You can also specify "PackageCount" for multiple packages, but only of the same type. If you can send 2 Medium Boxes, why not 1 Medium and 1 Small :)

Comment: Looks like the request needs to be populated with new objects before you send it, hence the error when refering to properties of [0].

Comment: No, I just wanted to point out that PackagingType does not exist at the LineItems collection, hence you cannot create LineItems with different package types. The PackageType is at the top level